# Unable to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am in the process of migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio. In order to do so I have been following the instructions on the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). I managed to successfully export my project from Eclipse to create my `build.gradle` file.

Now when attempting to import said `build.gradle` file into Android Studio I am constantly presented with the following error:
[image]

Now, I would love to also show a screen of the IDE log to provide more detail but quite frankly I have no idea where the "Help" button is :/

I've searched around the internet and it does not seem like anyone else has had this issue.
I've updated Android Studio to the latest version by the way so that's not the cause. As a final point, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Shell.

Comment: Have you set PATH to Android SDK and to build tools?

Comment: Well I can create a new project just fine, so I assume that's not the problem.

Comment: Try to leave the libraries as they are. And add them from modules. Try without gradle.